# Firefox does not stay in ٬Never Remeber History in VirtualBox ٬

Tags: virtualbox, firefox

I have changed many times the setting of firefox ٬Never remember the history٬ but this setting will return to ٬Custom private browser٬‌ and cause auto form fill again. This is installed in a guest machine, virtual box v6.1, ubuntu20.

Comment: Are you reloading snapshots?

Comment: Its auto filling form spec shows up when the custom private is on. Actually firefox keep the setting as "Never" in ubuntu but when it comes to VirtualBox it will return the setting to custom as  "open private browser", no matter how many times I try to push it back to Never remember history.